# Using WP page password protection as defacto login

Tags: posts, menus, pages, login, password

I am trying to secure certain parts/pages of a site within a multisite but I want to avoid using a proper WP user login system to add them to the users table. Using SSO to authenticate users across multisite that hooks into company Active Directory and I do not want visitors to be able to get subscriber roles across the multisite.

So I have explored using the password protect system to provide a 'light' sort of defacto login system. Currently the 'protected' menu is hidden until user logs in by going to the 'login' page (if they accidentally hit any protected page, they are redirected to login page). When the use the correct password, they then can access the remaining content on that page and also the 'protected' version of the menu appears.

All well and good. However, if the user goes to any other page, the menu then reverts back to the public menu and of course use will not see protected menu until they go back to the 'unlocked' page.

For more information, please see my earlier question - [Is it possible to show a different WP menu when using password protected pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283486/is-it-possible-to-show-a-different-wp-menu-when-using-password-protected-pages)

Is there any solution to get around this issue? Can I set a global/flag variable that will run every time a page is loaded to check if user has 'unlocked' the protected section?

The only other solution I can think of is putting the 'protected' pages into a sidebar widget on the protected page, but not particularly the optimal solution I am seeking.

Comment: You can cookie them. Once they're logged in, add a WP cookie and in your theme files, check for the presence of the cookie. If it's there, show the protected menu; if not, show the regular menu.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion WebElaine, I will give it a shot. However, doesn't the WP core already add the cookie? Also the cookie will the cookie only be detected if user has successfully entered in correct password?

Comment: If you are using full-on WordPress logins (even with SSO, you're working with a WP User) then yes, Core already adds a cookie. You mentioned above that you're looking for a "lite" login that does not create a WP role, in which case you'd need to deal with cookies yourself. And that's correct, you'd need to make sure your code only cookies the visitor if they log in successfully, not when they submit the form.